# execute assembly in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I have two DLL assemblies  from which I can read cpr card 
but this DLL is updating every time , and I don't want to update my program every time the DLL is updated so I want to give the user the right to write  the path of updated DLL , I mean I don't want to open the project and change the reference to new one

I usually import the last updated DLL

```
using mcSCLibrary;
```

and then I canuse this class

mcSCManager cpr = new mcSCManager();

and this is the content of mcSCManager class

```
namespace mcSCLibrary
{
 [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
 [ProgId("mcSCLibrary.Manager")]
 [Guid("26F0BCF0-D7AE-49AB-87B1-4817E1A4FE9B")]
 [ComVisible(true)]
public class mcSCManager : ImcSCManager
{
    public mcSCManager();

    public bool IsReadCompleted { get; }
    public string Log { get; }
    public mcSmartcard Smartcard { get; set; }

    public bool InitializesSmartcard();
    public bool ReadSmartcard();
}
}
```

and I use object of the mcSCManager class to take the data from the card and keep then en textbox :

```
  lbl_fullname.Text = cpr.Smartcard.FullNameEn.ToString();
            lbl_cpr.Text = cpr.Smartcard.CPRNO.ToString();
```

now I found out way that will load the DLL file but I cannot use these object to call the same methods and take data from the card

this is the assembly :

```
 Assembly IDCardManager = System.Reflection.Assembly
            .LoadFile ("C:\\Users\\DELL USER\\Desktop\\eVMSClient_src_20180127\\eVms_reader\\bin\\BH.CIO.Smartcard.IDCardManager.dll");



 var cpr3 = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("BH.CIO.Smartcard.IDCardManager.CardManager, BH.CIO.Smartcard.IDCardManager ", true));
```

now if use cpr3 to call the same method then error is there :

```
 lbl_fullname.Text = cpr3.Smartcard.FullNameEn.ToString();
```

can any one help me please , either to do this way or some other ways , suggestion , or opinions that will do same functionality

thankyou

Comment: When you keep saying DDL do you actually mean DLL?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error 3 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Smartcard' and no extension method 'Smartcard' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) this is the error

Comment: Have you tried recompiling your solution? Or cleaning and recompiling?

Comment: @ahmed_khudhair Also, the best way for you to maintain a absolute reference to a specific DLL is either storing its solution in a server with a fixed IP address or to make a NuGet package out of it. The main difference is that with NuGet, the client apps will only get the latest changes when they update their version, while having it in a server will always push the latest changes to them.

Comment: instead of  adding reference to the project and use its classes ,  and methods , I want to load assembly in project and uses its class and methods

Comment: You may use `dynamic` or better re-think your design. How do you think compiler may generate code for _unknown_ (at compile-time) types?!?!